# multiple record update using scheduled-triggered flow

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

I have a user case to update more than 2000 records at the end of each month. When a condition of the parent record is true a child record need to be updated. One parent record is having only one child record and can be more than 2000 parent records for each month. My flow picks first 100 records and then fires 101 SOQL error.

I collect all parent records and loop through to get the corresponding child record. As it it is running a SOQL query for each loop it hit the governor limit

[image]

Comment: assuming TA is the parent, why aren't you making that the object associated with the Schedule-triggered Flow Start element? -- then SFDC takes care of the batching for you and you will be far less likely to run into governor limits

Answer (score 1):

To avoid governor limits you should choose parent object with according conditions in the flow start element.[image]

This avoids having to use Get element.

After that the only element you need is an update element similar to this:[image]

Schedule triggered flow are treated the same as record triggered flows as they are bulkified bysalesforce. You should only consider what you want to do with the specific record and the flow will do the rest. Source https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5